# Failed to retrieve value from QCombobox - casting QVariant to const pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, casting, qt5

I don't know if the conversion of a QVariant into a custom (non-QObject) class const pointer is possible; for example with the `value()` function.

The [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value) says the following:

> Call canConvert() to find out whether a type can be converted. If the
>   value cannot be converted, a default-constructed value will be
>   returned.

Here is my code; it's located in a subclass of QComboBox and I'm trying to retrieve the current data and cast it as `const MyClass*`:

```
QVariant var = currentData(); // of the QComboBox
const MyClass* myObject = NULL;
if(var.canConvert<const MyClass *>())
{
    cout << "Conversion possible" << endl;
    myObject = var.value<const MyClass*>();
}
else
    cout << "Conversion impossible!!" << endl;

if(f == NULL)
    cout << "null pointer!!" << endl;
else if(myObject->getMyProperty() == 0)
    cout << "MyProperty is zero!" << endl;
```

I have declared:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(const MyClass*)
```

in MyClass header. In the output, I get `"Conversion possible"` at the creation of the QComboBox, then `"Conversion impossible!!" "null pointer!!"` and then, when I actually call the function in the code snippet, all I get is:

```
"Conversion possible"
"MyProperty is zero!"
```

MyProperty = 0 is set in the default constructor of MyClass. All the MyClass values in the QComboBox have myProperty set to a different value than 0.

My question is: if the conversion is possible, then why does the pointer created point to a default-constructed value?

**EDIT:** Here is some additional important code requested; the QComboBox initialization.

```
void MainWindow::prepareObjects()
{
    comboBox = new MyComboBox(this); // this is a member variable and MyComboBox inherits from QComboBox
    ObjectList ol; // contains a map of objects already defined
    map<QString, const MyClass*> themap = ol.getObjects();
    for(map<QString, const MyClass*>::iterator it = themap.begin(); it != themap.end(); ++it)
    {
        const MyClass myObject = *it->second;
        QIcon icon(QPixmap(":/images/objects/" + it->first + ".png"));
        comboBox->addItem(icon, myObject.getName(), QVariant::fromValue(&myObject));
    }
    comboBox->show();
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this solves your problem, but I had to call `qRegisterMetaType<MyClass *>("MyClass *");` additionally (before QApplication)

Comment: qRegisterMetaType is worth the try but Q_DECLARE_METATYPE should be enough for QVariant. How did you add the data to the combo box?

Comment: Thank you for answering. qRegisterMetaType unfortunately doesn't improve the output. I added the elements in the QComboBox by iterating on a `std::map<QString, const MyClass*>` . They are correctly added (I can print the keys and values). Like this: `comboBox->addItem(icon, myObject.getName(), QVariant::fromValue(&myObject));`

Comment: There are incoherences in these pieces of code. You should edit your question as an [MCVE](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwin3-zk5ZPOAhVJ1hoKHcn9BD0QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=djWR1ile3-amWJF3iBhcrQ&bvm=bv.128153897,d.d2s)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, unlike what I had thought, in the QComboBox initialization (edited question with corresponding code). The first pieces of code (QVariant cast) work fine.

The right way to add items to the QComboBox from the map was this:

```
void MainWindow::prepareObjects()
{
    comboBox = new MyComboBox(this);
    ObjectList ol;
    map<QString, const MyClass*> themap = ol.getObjects();
    for(map<QString, const MyClass*>::iterator it = themap.begin(); it != themap.end(); ++it)
    {
        const MyClass* myObject = it->second; // SAME TYPE AS IN THE MAP AND COMBOBOX
        QIcon icon(QPixmap(":/images/objects/" + it->first + ".png"));
        comboBox->addItem(icon, myObject->getName(), QVariant::fromValue(myObject)); // no '&'
    }
    comboBox->show();
}
```

My map and QComboBox store `MyClass*` items. I basically had an intermediary variable of type `MyClass` (no pointer), in which I stored the value of my object in the map, and then I took its address for the QComboBox. This created a wild pointer in the combobox, with 0 or random (huge) numbers as Integer member variables of the object, and Segmentation Fault for the QString variables.

What I still don't understand is that the values in the QComboBox are still correct when I try to access them directly after inserting them. The problem happens outside the initialization method, in a MyComboBox slot; this is where the first piece of code in the question comes from.

So I still don't have a precise answer for this:

> If the conversion is possible, then why does the pointer created point
>   to a default-constructed value?

Except that what I thought a default-constructed value was a wild, or dangling pointer.